# Assigning date value to data field with php format

Tags: php, html

When using the following format I have no issues with printing the servers'date.

```
<input id="u&date" type="date" readonly  class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" >
```

[It works here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PN0u.png)

But in the other hand, when i try to change the format of date it wont display:

```
<input id="u&date" type="date" readonly  class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y");?>" >
```

[it doesnt work here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr2QD.png)

Comment: Are you trying to change date format? Be Specific.

Comment: yes that is indeed the problem, i just want to change the date format, but for some reason it stops working when echoing that date

Comment: I added the answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change type="date" to type="text" in second input. See below:

```
<input id="u&date" type="date" readonly  class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" >

<input id="u&date" type="text" readonly  class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y");?>" >
```

When you have input type=date, the system is formats/validates the date again. You have dashes in your 1st input, but it gets changed to slashes. See below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If you’re satisfied by the answer, just go ahead and accept it please.